# Bottle -- Redirect output of SimpleTemplate to static file

Tags: python, bottle

I'm wanting to implement a caching system for a bottle site I've been working on. The idea is that a couple of routes take a bit longer to render, so, if the sqlite table hasn't been updated since the html file was generated, I'll return that, if it has, I'll retrieve the rows from the database and save that to a file and return that.

Probably someone has already done this, so any tips for redirecting the output of a '.tpl' template to a '.html' file would be appreciated.

I've looked at some general caching libs but they seem to work by refreshing the cache at particular time intervals whereas I want to refresh when the database changes.

Thanks.

Edit: I'm using Apache as a reverse proxy, cheroot as the app server.

Answer (score 0):

First you need a cache object.  A dict is a great option.

```
cachetpl = {}
lastupdated = time.time()
cache = Cache()
```

Then create a class to handle stuff in your dict:

```
class Cache(object):
    def __init__(self):
        global lastupdated
        self.lastupdated = lastupdated
        global cachetpl
        self.cachetpl = cachetpl

    def keys(self):
        return self.cachetpl.keys()

    def lastupdate(self):
        return self.lastupdate

    def meta(self, clienthash, zipcode=None):
        return self.cachetpl[clienthash]
```

Then you need to setup a pulse to check for changes, maybe checking lastupdated column of your SQL storage.

```
@staticmethod
def update():
    global cachetpl
    global lastupdated
    if not cachetpl:
        return None, None
    PSQL = ''' SELECT key, meta FROM schema.table WHERE lastupdated >= %s '''        
    changes = db.fetchall(PSQL, lastupdated)
    if changes:
        numchange = len(changes)
        for x in changes:
            cachetpl[x[0]] = x[1]
        lastupdated = time.time()
        return len(cachetpl), numchange
    else:
        lastupdated = nz.now()
        return None, None
```

How you setup this pulse is up to you.  I use a python library called `scheduler` and use gevent for my app for async.  Works awesome.

Now you just call your class `Cache()` and feed it whatever data you want.  My suggestion is that instead of returning the template, you save it first in your database, and then return it.  Let the call to the route check for a cached version before rendering it.  Then you could modify the update to render pages in the background if data changes, so the next call to the cache is the new data.